# "argument is not numeric" error in R using aggregate() inside a user-defined function

Tags: r, function, aggregate

I have a dataset and I'm trying to run summary statistics (mean, sd, etc.) of several different feature variables against one different feature variable (all numeric), so I'm trying to define a function that I can just pass column names to. I've written code that works perfectly well outside of a function definition:

```
mystats <- aggregate(thisvar ~ othervar, data = mydf, function(x) 
    c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), mymn = min(x), mymx = max(x)))
```

. . . but as soon as I put that code inside of a function definition, like so:

```
mystatvars <- function(othervar, thisvar) {
  mystats <- aggregate(thisvar ~ othervar, data = mydf, function(x) 
    c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), mymn = min(x), mymx = max(x)))
  return(mystats)
}
```

. . . I get warning messages, "Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
NAs introduced by coercion"

I've tried passing the function the names of the columns in the dataset, in quotes, as arguments (which has worked in self-defined functions that don't use aggregate), but that hasn't worked here. (I've also tried passing them without quote marks, but then it just returns an "object not found" error.) Please help?

(I'm running R 4.1.0 in RStudio on a Mac.)

Comment: do `aggregate(reformulate(othervar, thisvar), data = mydf, ...)`

Comment: Formulas tend to use non-standard evaluation, so it worked in the first example because you were referencing *real column names*, as in `"thisvar" %in% names(mydf)`. However, in your function, you're suggesting that `thisvar %in% names(mydf)` (no quotes), which is a very different issue. If you debug your `function` and type in `thisvar ~ othervar, you'll see that it's using the symbols `thisvar` and `othervar`, not the string contents of those two variables. Compare that response with `reformulate(othervar, thisvar)` (note the reversal!).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your warning messages using `mtcars` dataset:

This one works:

```
mystats <- aggregate(wt ~ vs, data = mtcars, function(x) 
  c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), mymn = min(x), mymx = max(x)))
```

This one produces the warning messages:

```
mystatvars <- function(othervar, thisvar) {
  mystats <- aggregate(thisvar ~ othervar, data = mtcars, function(x) 
    c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), mymn = min(x), mymx = max(x)))
  return(mystats)
}

mystatvars("vs", "wt")
```

```
  othervar thisvar.mean thisvar.sd thisvar.mymn thisvar.mymx
1       vs         <NA>       <NA>           wt           wt
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

The problem is that when you call your function (`mystatvars("vs", "wt")`), `"vs"` and `"wt"` do not become the formula you expected

Instead, what happened is

```
othervar <- "vs"
thisvar <- "wt"

aggregate(thisvar ~ othervar, data = mtcars, function(x) 
  c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), mymn = min(x), mymx = max(x)))
```

which produces the warning messages again.

So what you need is to build a formula properly using `othervar` and `thisvar`. As @Onyambu mentioned `reformulate()` can do the job. Checkout `?reformulate` for more details.

```
mystatvars <- function(othervar, thisvar) {
  mystats <- aggregate(reformulate(othervar, thisvar), data = mtcars, function(x) 
    c(mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x), mymn = min(x), mymx = max(x)))
  return(mystats)
}
```

Another sidenote is that your dataset should be an input of your function as well.